# Generics with inner classes in kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a sealed class which contain some data classes as shown below. Is there a way to know which class (D1, D2, D3) I am working with in T1.printclassname()?

```
sealed class A {
  data class D1 { }
  data class D2 { }
  data class D3 { }
}
class T1 {
    fun <E : A> printclassname(val c: E) {

    }
}
```

And trying the same with inner classes

```
internal class B {
  inner class X1 { }
  inner class X2 { }
  inner class X3 { }
}
class T2 {
    fun <E : B> printclassname(val c: E) {
      if (c is B.X1){
         // some op.
        }
    }
}
```

The printclassname() shoudl accept any object of D1, D2, D3. and printclassname1 should accept any object of X1, X2, X3

Comment: What do you mean by "access those inner classes through generics"? Just getting their names? pls specify

Comment: @WilliMentzel Thanks for responding. By accessing I mean I want to work with respective objects. And The flow varies based on which data class I am dealing with.

Comment: what's wrong with Sergey's code?

Answer (score 1):

You should inherit classes `A` and `B` respectively:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    printClassName1(A.D1("some value"))
    printClassName(B().X1())
}

sealed class A {
    // Data classes must have at least one primary constructor parameter
    data class D1(val p: String): A() { }
    data class D2(val p: String): A() { }
    data class D3(val p: String): A() { }
}

// make this class open to be able to inherit
open class B {
    inner class X1: B() { }
    inner class X2: B() { }
    inner class X3: B() { }
}
fun <E : B> printClassName(c: E) {
    println("name=${c::class.simpleName}")
}

fun <E : A> printClassName1(c: E) {
    println("name=${c::class.simpleName}")
}
```

**The output:**

```
name=D1
name=X1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Sergey. When I am tring something like below, I am getting incomptabel error. if (c is B.X1) in printClassName()

Comment: All should compile. On what line and in which method do you have an error?

Comment: updated the post. the if satement is throwing error. Exact error is imcomptable type B.X1 and E

Comment: just use my code and it will work. You need to inherit `B` class.